# BlackBerry Messages in notification bar issue

Tags: blackberry, notifications, message

i tried to use this example,

```
 //Register the ApplicationMessageFolder
 //ReadableListImpl source is available in the messagelistdemo.
 ApplicationMessageFolder folder =      ApplicationMessageFolderRegistry.getInstance().registerFolder(
    0x33c7ce29883abe5fL, "Test Folder", new ReadableListImpl());

//DemoMessage source is available in the messagelistdemo.
DemoMessage msg = new DemoMessage("me@here.com", "Pizza Toppings", 
    "What would you like on your pizza?", System.currentTimeMillis());
folder.fireElementAdded(msg);

//Display the application indicator icon.
ApplicationIndicatorRegistry reg = ApplicationIndicatorRegistry.getInstance();    

 EncodedImage image = EncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("Indicator.png");

 ApplicationIcon icon = new ApplicationIcon(image);

 ApplicationIndicator indicator = reg.register(icon, false, true);
 indicator.setIcon(icon);
 indicator.setVisible(true);
```

I am able to see the indicatoe icon, but the message is not shown.

Could someone please tell me whats wrong ??

BR,
Suppi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596507/blackberry-notification-message-issue) seems relevent to your issue. However, reading the tuturial you reference ([here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/tkb/articleprintpage/tkb-id/java_dev@tkb/article-id/521)) it seems that you're not seeing the message on the home screen but can you confirm it is there if you enter your message app?

Comment: Nope unfortunately, i don't see the message in the Message App

Comment: When debugging you don't see any exceptions? Can you confirm the DemoMessage method you call is executing in its entirety or is it failing early but hiding an exception?

Comment: I debugged the application, i don't get any exceptions. This was working earlier. After i reloaded the OS it stopped working.

Comment: I think you really should read the other thread I posted in my answer as they describe your problem exactly the same. It most likely has to do with your application creating "a new ReadableListImpl each time the menu item gets invoked"

Comment: hi sorry, i think i wasn't looking at the right place, i found the message in the Message app, but how can i bring it to the status bar on the home screen

Comment: Never mind i got it working, ApplicationFolderIntegrationConfig i changed the second parameter to true.